# Observable Fields with include tag

Tags: android, android-databinding

i'm new to android databinding library and i was trying to setup Observable fields for my arrayList and access it in xml, however my xml has an include tag to which i'd like to pass this data and i've set it up as below.

**fragment_farmers.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <import type="java.util.ArrayList"/>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
            name="fragment"
            type="****.****.com.android.Fragments.FarmersFragment"
            />
        <variable
            name="farmers"
            type="****.****.com.android.Fragments.FarmersFragment.FarmerBindData"
            />
            />

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <include
            layout="@layout/content_farmers"
            android:id="@+id/content"
            app:farmers="@{farmers}"/>
...
```

**content_farmers.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <import type="java.util.ArrayList"/>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
            name="farmers"
            type="ArrayList"
            />
    </data>
```

**FarmersFragment.java**

```
...
FarmerBindData bindData = new FarmerBindData();
 binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_farmers, container, false);
        binding.setFragment(this);
        binding.setFarmers(bindData);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
...
    public void getFarmers() {
        try {
            farmers.clear();
            List<JsonObject> temp = ...;
            farmers.addAll(temp);
            bindData.farmers.set(farmers);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private class FarmerBindData{
       public final  ObservableField<ArrayList<JsonObject>> farmers = new ObservableField<>();
    }
...
```

*How can i be able to retrieve this data in the include tag* because this isn't working so far, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding line

```
binding.executePendingBindings()
```

after

```
bindData.farmers.set(farmers);
```